# Get download progress from SCNScene url

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I'm working with ARKit, I have trouble getting download progress from SCNScene url. This is my code:

```
func downloadModel(hitTestResult: ARHitTestResult) {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        // create loading view
        // I WANT TO GET DOWNLOAD PROGRESS HERE
        let loading = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...\(downloadProgressValueHere)%", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
        loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

        loading.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
        self.present(loading, animated: true, completion: nil)

        // download 3d model from server
        let myURL = URL(string: "http://www.mydownloadlink.com")
        let scene = try! SCNScene(url: myURL!, options: nil)
        let node = (scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "parentNode", recursively: true))!
        self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)

        // dismiss loading view
        loading.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

How can I get download progress to "Please wait..." message? Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

It is my understanding that whilst it appears that the following method would take a remote URL in actuality it doesn't (although I could be wrong):

```
convenience init(url: URL, 
         options: [SCNSceneSource.LoadingOption : Any]? = nil) throws
```

Anyway to answer your question here is an example for you (which is probably a bit OTT, but hopefully it will help others as well).

Lets say we an `SCNScene` file at the following `URL`:

```
http://stackOverflow.com/stackOverFlow.scn
```

Firstly we need to create variables for our `ProgressInfo` like so:

```
 var loading: UIAlertController!
 var loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
 var downloadString: String = "Downloading"
```

Then what we will do is create a URLSession to download the file like so:

```
 /// Downloads An SCNFile From A Remote URL
 func downloadSceneTask(){

        //1. Get The URL Of The SCN File
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://stackOverflow.com/stackOverFlow.scn") else { return }

        //2. Create The Download Session
        let downloadSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSession.shared.configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

        //3. Create The Download Task & Run It
        let downloadTask = downloadSession.downloadTask(with: url)
        downloadTask.resume()

        //4. Show The Progress Alert
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

           self.loading = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: self.downloadString , preferredStyle: .alert)

           let loadingIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 50, height: 50))
           loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
           loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
           loadingIndicator.startAnimating();

           self.loading.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
           self.present(self.loading, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

 }
```

Note that I have create a `variable` caused `downloadString` which we change later.

We will then make reference to following URLSession Delegates e.g:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDownloadDelegate {

}
```

Which for our example will call the following functions:

The 1st to track the progress of our download in which you can handle things like showing the progress in a `HUD` or using a `progressIndicator`:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
                    didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64,
                    totalBytesWritten: Int64,
                    totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

        print("Downloaded \(totalBytesWritten) / Of \(totalBytesExpectedToWrite) Bytes")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.loading.message = "Downloaded \(totalBytesWritten) / Of \(totalBytesExpectedToWrite) Bytes"
    }

}
```

The 2nd to handle when the file has downloaded:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {

//1. Remove The Loading View
    loading.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

//2. Create The Filename
let fileURL = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("stackOverFlow.scn")

//3. Copy It To The Documents Directory
do {
    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: location, to: fileURL)

    print("Successfuly Saved File \(fileURL)")

    //4. Load The Model
    loadModel()

} catch {

    print("Error Saving: \(error)")
 }
}
```

Note that in this method I am making use of the following function to retrieve and copy the downloaded file to the `documents directory`:

```
/// Returns The Documents Directory
///
/// - Returns: URL
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {

let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
return documentsDirectory

}
```

Once the file has been downloaded and copied across we then (4) call our `loadModel function` like so:

```
/// Loads The SCNFile From The Documents Directory
func loadModel(){

    //1. Get The Path Of The Downloaded File
    let downloadedScenePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("stackOverFlow.scn")

    do {

        //2. Load The Scene Remembering The Init Takes ONLY A Local URL
        let modelScene =  try SCNScene(url: downloadedScenePath, options: nil)

        //3. Create A Node To Hold All The Content
        let modelHolderNode = SCNNode()

        //4. Get All The Nodes From The SCNFile
        let nodeArray = modelScene.rootNode.childNodes

        //5. Add Them To The Holder Node
        for childNode in nodeArray {
            modelHolderNode.addChildNode(childNode as SCNNode)
        }

        //6. Set The Position
        modelHolderNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -1.5)

        //7. Add It To The Scene
        self.augmentedRealityView?.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(modelHolderNode)


    } catch  {
        print("Error Loading Scene")
    }

}
```

Please note that this is a very crude example, and doesn't cover things like checking if the file exists, scaling etc, but it should be enough to help you achieve what you are looking for...