# Swift Load A 3d Asset from URL Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit

I have a simple HTTP server running and Im trying to fetch this scenekit from my local server but IT shows me NIL error, or Error Loading Scene. I dont understand how to load this model from my simple local host. How to configure my code so that I will be able to fetch any Scenekit from remote or local server.

Thanks in advance

```
  do {
                let shipScene = try SCNScene(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: "http://localhost:8080/chair.scn") , options: nil)



            // Set the scene to the view
            sceneView.scene = shipScene
            let shipNode = shipScene.rootNode.childNodes.first!
            shipNode.position = SCNVector3Zero
            shipNode.position.z = 0.15
            shipNode.position.y = 0
            shipNode.position.x = 0
            let action = SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotate(by: .pi, around: SCNVector3(0, 1, 0), duration: 5))
            shipNode.runAction(action)
            planeNode.addChildNode(shipNode)
            node.addChildNode(planeNode)

        } catch {
            print("ERROR loading scene")
        }
```

Comment: You have to download that in document directory and then use it

Comment: Oh can you please help me how to do it ?

Comment: Download scene kit file with use of URLSession or Alamofire whatever you are using into document directory and after downloaded you can load it here is example https://stackoverflow.com/a/50023847/4601900

Comment: @user9538877 Can you send you scn files .Otherwise can you please which format i can take data from server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Prashant said you will need to actually download the model first before using it.

The first thing you would need to do therefore is create a URLSession to download the file e.g:

```
/// Downloads An SCNFile From A Remote URL
func downloadSceneTask(){

        //1. Get The URL Of The SCN File
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8080/chair.scn") else { return }

        //2. Create The Download Session
        let downloadSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSession.shared.configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

        //3. Create The Download Task & Run It
        let downloadTask = downloadSession.downloadTask(with: url)
        downloadTask.resume()      
    }

 }
```

We will then make reference to the `URLSessionDownloadDelegate` e.g.:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, URLSessionDownloadDelegate { }
```

Now we have the delegate hooked up we need to  make use of the following `callback` to copy our downloaded file to the `Documents Directory` of the device:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {

    //1. Create The Filename
    let fileURL = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("chair.scn")

    //2. Copy It To The Documents Directory
    do {
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: location, to: fileURL)

        print("Successfuly Saved File \(fileURL)")

        //3. Load The Model
        loadModel()

    } catch {

        print("Error Saving: \(error)")
    }

}
```

Note that in the function I am using the following helper method to get the Documents Directory:

```
/// Returns The Documents Directory
///
/// - Returns: URL
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {

let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
return documentsDirectory

}
```

Once the file has been downloaded and copied across we then call our `loadModel function` (3) like so:

```
/// Loads The SCNFile From The Documents Directory
func loadModel(){

    //1. Get The Path Of The Downloaded File
    let downloadedScenePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("chair.scn")

    do {

        //2. Load The Scene Remembering The Init Takes ONLY A Local URL
        let modelScene =  try SCNScene(url: downloadedScenePath, options: nil)

        //3. Create A Node To Hold All The Content
        let modelHolderNode = SCNNode()

        //4. Get All The Nodes From The SCNFile
        let nodeArray = modelScene.rootNode.childNodes

        //5. Add Them To The Holder Node
        for childNode in nodeArray {
            modelHolderNode.addChildNode(childNode as SCNNode)
        }

        //6. Set The Position
        modelHolderNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -1.5)

        //7. Add It To The Scene
        self.augmentedRealityView?.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(modelHolderNode)


    } catch  {
        print("Error Loading Scene")
    }

}
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Hi @BlackMirrorz can you share your 3d model url